# Clip WFS layer with QGIS on import

Tags: qgis, postgis, wfs

I have a large WFS polygon layer and I want to use `query builder` to clip it before importing to desktop app.
To do this, I have created predefined polygon ( QGIS layer named: `clip_boundary` ) which I want to use a boundary to clip data.

Query builder SQl statement:

```
SELECT * FROM wfs_table WHERE ST_Contains( wkb_geometry,clip_boundary.geometry)
```

Where `wfs_table` is table I want to clip.
I get following error:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to reference a layer from your local project in the SQL Query Composer. You can only make queries to the WFS.

If it is always the same polygon you can write something like this:

[image]